# I want to remove the whole list using the splice in javascript when clear link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, array-splice

Below is the code that I have written in angular JS and HTML. I have a list of groceries, there is remove link beside each list to remove the item. I also added a clear list link when clicked on it, it should clear the whole list. But when I click on clear list, it deletes only 1 item at a time whereas it should delete the whole list. I have used splice to remove and trying to implement splice only to clear the list as well.

```
   <html ng-app="nameApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="nameCtrl">
The list of groceries:</br>
<ul>
<a href="" ng-click="clear(name)">clear list</a>
<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}
<a href="" ng-click="remove(name)">remove</a>
</li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp',[]);
nameApp.controller('nameCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.names = ['Eggs','Milk','Bread','Cheese'];
$scope.remove=function(name){
var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
$scope.names.splice(i,1);
}
$scope.clear=function(name){
var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
$scope.names.splice(i,5);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `splice`, just assign empty array to the variable.

```
$scope.clear=function(name){
    $scope.names = [];
};
```